# How to remove string pattern and all the string behind that pattern?

Tags: string, go, mapping

For Example :

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    pattern := "helloworld."
    myString := "foo.bar.helloworld.qwerty.zxc.helloworld.asd"
    fmt.Println(removeFromPattern(pattern, myString))
}

func removeFromPattern(p, ms string) string {
    // I confused here (in efficient way)
}
```

Wanted output :

```
qwerty.zxc.helloworld.asd
```

How do I get that wanted output, also how to remove the first `pattern` and all the strings behind that pattern from `myString` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Using `_, after, _ = strings.Cut(ms, p)`, try [this](https://go.dev/play/p/xu0XSGbR0AZ):

```
func removeFromPattern(p, ms string) (after string) {
    _, after, _ = strings.Cut(ms, p) // before and after sep.
    return
}
```

Which uses `strings.Index` :

```
// Cut slices s around the first instance of sep,
// returning the text before and after sep.
// The found result reports whether sep appears in s.
// If sep does not appear in s, cut returns s, "", false.
func Cut(s, sep string) (before, after string, found bool) {
    if i := Index(s, sep); i >= 0 {
        return s[:i], s[i+len(sep):], true
    }
    return s, "", false
}
```

---

2- Using `strings.Index`, try [this](https://go.dev/play/p/u0YRlCDAhiM):

```
func removeFromPattern(p, ms string) string {
    i := strings.Index(ms, p)
    if i == -1 {
        return ""
    }
    return ms[i+len(p):]
}
```

---

3- Using `strings.Split`, try [this](https://go.dev/play/p/M0PALo7K8TC):

```
func removeFromPattern(p, ms string) string {
    a := strings.Split(ms, p)
    if len(a) != 2 {
        return ""
    }
    return a[1]
}
```

---

4- Using `regexp`, try [this](https://go.dev/play/p/zruIh57rmo6)

```
func removeFromPattern(p, ms string) string {
    a := regexp.MustCompile(p).FindStringSubmatch(ms)
    if len(a) < 2 {
        return ""
    }
    return a[1]
}
```

Comment: `strings.Cut` could be used as well https://go.dev/play/p/gqJ6KoQV9jq

Comment: This solution solved my confusion, I used `strings.Cut`. Thanks a lot anw!

Answer (score 1):

[strings.Split](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split) is enough

```golang
func main() {
    pattern := "helloworld."
    myString := "foo.bar.helloworld.qwerty.zxc"

    res := removeFromPattern(pattern, myString)
    fmt.Println(res)
}

func removeFromPattern(p, ms string) string {
    parts := strings.Split(ms, p)
    if len(parts) > 1 {
        return parts[1]
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was about to post. [Here is a playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/IR-GiJwJ5l3).

Comment: This may cause problem if 'myString' contains more than 2 'helloworld.'

Comment: @HaryoBagasAssyafah your question didn't say that

Comment: If there is no match, this will panic, so may want to check the length of slice returned by `Split`.

Comment: Also, the return type should be`string` not `any`.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
func removeFromPattern(p, ms string) string {
    return strings.ReplaceAll(ms, p, "")
}
func main() {
    pattern := "helloworld."
    myString := "foo.bar.helloworld.qwerty.zxc"
    res := removeFromPattern(pattern, myString)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution will not replace/blank-out what comes before the match.